# Karma: How to handle multiple calls to a spy that have different responses?

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a method that I want to test, inside the method I call document.getElementById for two separate elements. In the past I've just created a spy on the document.getElementById method and set the return value to a mocked element of my choosing. However now I need the first call to the spy to return one mocked element, and the next call to return a second unique element and I'm not sure how I can accomplish this.

Code behind:

```
private scrollParentToChild(): void {
  let parent: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('.theParent');
  let child: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('.theChild');
  parent.scrollTop = child.offsetTop;
}
```

Unit Test:

```
describe('scrollParentToChild', () => {
  it('should set the parents scrollTop to the offsetTop of the child', () => {
    let parent: any = {
      scrollTop: 0
    };
    let child: any = {
      offsetTop: 100
    };
    spyOn(document, 'getElementById').and.returnValue(parent); // Okay this will return the parent for both calls to document.getElementById now, but how do I make it only return this for the first call and then return child for the second call.
    component.scrollParentToChild();
    expect(parent.scrollTop).toEqual(child.offsetTop);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you're on a relatively recent version of Jasmine (at least 2.4), you should be able to take advantage of the `.and.returnValues(...)` method on Jasmine spies. You can use this as follows:

```
spyOn(document, 'getElementById').and.returnValues(parent, child); //note the 's'!
```

This way, the first call to `getElementById` will be return `parent`, the second will return `child`, and subsequent calls will return `undefined`.

[Jasmine docs for returnValues](https://jasmine.github.io/2.4/introduction#section-Spies:_%3Ccode%3Eand.returnValues%3C/code%3E)

Answer (score 0):

Jasmine spies are really simple and lack features. For more complex scenarios Sinon stubs can be used instead:

```
const mockedGetElementById = sinon.stub(document, 'getElementById');
mockedGetElementById.withArgs('.theParent').returns(parent);
mockedGetElementById.withArgs('.theChild').returns(child);
...
mockedGetElementById.restore();
```

It is possible to handle multiple calls manually with Jasmine spy. It would be possible to conditionally return the value depending on `document.getElementById.calls.count()`, but in this case it is function argument that defines return value, not the order. It will be something like that:

```
spyOn(document, 'getElementById').and.callFake((id) => {
  switch (id) {
    case '.theParent':
      return parent;
    case '.theChild':
      return child;
    default:
      throw new Error('Unexpected call');
  }  
});
```

It should be noticed that testing framework is Jasmine. It doesn't really matter if it runs with Karma or not in this case.